# How do you change parts of a string in each element of a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is part of a block of code to get a response of a list of games and details about each of them as JSON data from IGDB's API:

```
.then(response => {
    const collections = response.data;
    const images = [];
        
    collections.forEach(collection => {
      collection.cover.url.replace('t_thumb', 't_1080p')
      // let imageURL = collection.cover.url;
      // imageURL.replace('t_thumb', 't_1080p');
      // images.push(imageURL);
    })
})
```

In IGDB's database, they have different sizes and qualities for the game's cover, and you can access each type by changing a part of the URL from `t_thumb` to `t_1080p`. I tried to change that part of the URL by using forEach and .replace() as shown in the code, but the string does not change. I also tried adding each URL to a new array one by one by copying each element, replacing part of the string, and then inserting it into the new array (the commented-out code) but that did not work either. How can I change part of each string in the collections list?

Comment: Do. const myChangedCollection = collections.map(collection => collection.replace....

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Just to make sure, is there a way to change part of each string without having to make a new array? Or is that just not possible?

Comment: It should change the object by reference but I suspect you aren't returning the collections object from you .then callback. Unless there is some limitation to change an original response array.

Comment: There is no limitation or anything, it's just easier for me if am able to use the original list since the urls are all part of a larger object. However, I found an easy work around, so having a second list isn't bad. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah I know why. collection.cover.url = collection.cover.url.replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method returns a new string with the value(s) replaced. The `replace()` method does not change the original string.

Try this **:**

```
collection.cover.url = collection.cover.url.replace('t_thumb', 't_1080p')
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
let collections = [{
  cover: {
    url: 'alpha'
  }
}, {
  cover: {
    url: 't_thumb'
  }
}, {
  cover: {
    url: 'beta'
  }
}, {
  cover: {
    url: 't_thumb'
  }
}, {
  cover: {
    url: 't_thumb'
  }
}];

collections.forEach(collection => {
  collection.cover.url = collection.cover.url.replace('t_thumb', 't_1080p')
});

console.log(collections);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since strings in javascript are immutable, you can't modify the original string.

```
string.replace()
```

returns a new string after the modification. to get the changed string you need to assign the value returned from the `replace()` to the variable.

you can do it like this

```
collection.cover.url = collection.cover.url.replace('t_thumb', 't_1080p')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with spread operator and replace:

```
 const updatedCollections = collections.map(el => ({
    ...el,
    cover: { ...el.cover, url: el.cover.url.replace('t_thumb', 't_1080p') },
  }));
```